# Combine 2 arrays with time strings to 1 array of time ranges

Tags: php, arrays, time, merge, date-range

I have 2 arrays and I'd like to group them into one array:

```
$arrayA = Array
    (
        [0] => 08:00am
        [1] => 10:00am
        [2] => 12:00pm
        [3] => 02:00pm
        [4] => 04:00pm
        [5] => 06:00pm
        [6] => 08:00pm
        [7] => 10:00pm
    )

$arrayB = Array
    (
        [0] => 09:00am
        [1] => 11:00am
        [2] => 01:00pm
        [3] => 03:00pm
        [4] => 05:00pm
        [5] => 07:00pm
        [6] => 09:00pm
    )
```

I tried:

```
  foreach ($arrayA as $keeyy=>$val)
  {
      $arrC[] = $val." "."to"." ".$$arrayB[$keeyy];
  }
```

but my result was:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 7 in <b>C:\Users\user\Desktop\xammp\htdocs\Ea....on line <b>104</b><br />
Array
    (
        [0] => 08:00am to 09:00am
        [1] => 10:00am to 11:00am
        [2] => 12:00pm to 01:00pm
        [3] => 02:00pm to 03:00pm
        [4] => 04:00pm to 05:00pm
        [5] => 06:00pm to 07:00pm
        [6] => 08:00pm to 09:00pm
        [7] => 10:00pm to 
    )
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8:00am To 09:00am  
    [1] =>09:00am To 10:00am
    [2] =>10:00am To 11:00am
    [3] => 11:00am To 12:00pm
    [4] => 12:00pm To 1:00pm
    [5] => 1:00pm To 2:00pm
    [6] => 2:00pm To 3:00pm
    [7] => 3:00pm To 4:00pm
    [8] => 4:00pm To 5:00pm
    [9] => 5:00pm To 6:00pm
    [10] => 6:00pm To 7:00pm
    [11] => 7:00pm To 8:00pm
    [12] => 8:00pm To 9:00pm
    [13] => 9:00pm To 10:00pm
)
```

Comment: How do you know which value starts and which ends, they seem to vary throughout.

Comment: @Remy i can't seem to get my head around the for loop,any help please.Am a begginer in php

Comment: I wouldn't use `for` for this.. but logic is unclear to me. Anything `for` can do `foreach` can, but usually cleaner (presuming there is array).

Comment: @user3783243 ,question edited

Comment: This question has me asking more questions about how the data varies and if this is an XY problem.  Can we safely loop only on the first array? or might the second array be longer for some reason? Where are these arrays coming from? Is one always even and the other always odd? Are they always an hour apart?  It is such a niche task, I don't know if any future researchers will actually need this operation.  My [take on the task](https://3v4l.org/ruItt) but I won't answer because there are too many unknowns to provide a robust answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the arrays and map them to a timestamp and sort ascending.  Then just loop and get the current time and the next one based on key if it exists:

```
$all = array_merge($one, $two);
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', $all), $all);

foreach($all as $key => $time) {
    if(isset($all[$key + 1])) {
        $result[] = "$time To {$all[$key + 1]}";
    }
}
```

If they are already in order, the first array is the beginning, and they have the same count, then loop and use the key to get the end and save it for the beginning of the next:

```
foreach($one as $key => $time) {
    if(isset($prev)) {
        $result[] = "$prev To $time";
    }
    $prev = $two[$key];
    $result[] = "$time To $prev";
}
```